# Sqlite open helper insert else update?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I want to insert data successfully

Here is my code:

```
 public void insertData(String strTableName,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrListproductdatabase) {
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        for (int i = 0; i < arrListproductdatabase.size(); i++) {
            // cv.put(columnName, arrListOfRecord.get(i).get("name"));
            cv.put(columnproductname,
                    arrListproductdatabase.get(i).get("product"));
            cv.put(columnproductprice,
                    arrListproductdatabase.get(i).get("price"));
            cv.put(columnproductquantity,
                    arrListproductdatabase.get(i).get("quantity"));
            cv.put(columnproductid,
                    arrListproductdatabase.get(i).get("productID"));
            cv.put(columnresturantID,
                    arrListproductdatabase.get(i).get("resturantID"));

            db.insert(strTableName, null, cv);

        }
```

I want that when I have to press add button again, that time it should check if the product is already inserted, and in that condition it should update and all.

I don't want to create any duplicate value.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: explain you question correctly ,so that we can help u out

Comment: Its logical thing just check all the entries of the database while adding in if(condition) and in else part write your update query you will find many syntax to insert and update

Comment: ya but i am stored arraylist then how can you post it name to database helper?

Comment: traverse the arraylist in for loop and use compare function of java to check if the data is same

Comment: according to me i think you need to retrieve value from arraylist then the solution is simple traverse the arraylist in for loop and use compare function of java to check if the data is same. if any problem comment below it will notify me

Answer (score 0):

you can check for the distinct values in the db. please follow the link to have more details

[android check duplicate values before inserting data into database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658513/android-check-duplicate-values-before-inserting-data-into-database)

Answer (score 0):

Set 'Product' field as unique key. So when duplicate value arrives from standard `insert`, it will simply return -1 and the error message will be swallowed.

You can control the behavior by using `insertWithOnConflict (String table, String nullColumnHack, ContentValues initialValues, int conflictAlgorithm)` where you also specify a conflict algorithm that can be of values:

CONFLICT_ABORT 
CONFLICT_FAIL 
CONFLICT_IGNORE 
CONFLICT_REPLACE 
CONFLICT_ROLLBACK

Check out the reference for descrption of the [conflict resolution types](http://www.androidjavadoc.com/1.1_r1_src/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.ConflictAlgorithm.html).

There is also an `updateWithOnConflict`

Answer (score -1):

You can do that like this :

```
public boolean checkProduct(String product){

        // shold open database here
        Cursor mCursor = 
                db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, null, "product='" + product+"'", null, null, null, null, null);
        if(mCursor != null){
            mCursor.close();
            // shold close database here
            return true;
        }
        // shold close database first here also
        return false;
    }
```

Hope this helped you.

Comment: The usage of "product='"+product+"'" allows for SQLInjection attacks. Instead you should use "product = ?" and then supply the product in the next parameter