# Android Sqlite Cursor - Check if next row contains same value

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to compare cursor data, which is extracted from a SQLite database. It just has to be one column `cursor.getString(1);`

However, how can I check if that column has the same value in the next cursor row? (not the next column!) Using `cursor.moveToNext();`?

To paraphrase, I want to find a way to check column 1 for duplicate String entries using Cursor object.

Comment: Why don't you just extract unique data, by simply using the SQL keyword `DISTINCT` in your query?

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10658537/5908572), this is the code you might want to use:

```
String checkedValue = cursor.getString(1);

while(cursor.moveToNext()){
    String value = cursor.getString(1);
    if(value.equals(checkedValue)){ 
        // TODO: duplicate value found, do something
        break;
    }
}
```